# Custom Axis Scale for Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plotting program that currently takes an array that goes from 12-2000 on both the x and y axis.

```
img2 = plt.imshow(data1,interpolation='nearest',cmap = cmap2, norm=MidpointNormalize(midpoint=p50)
        ,extent=[12,2000,12,2000], origin='lower')
```

This method works, but it gives me poor control over my axes. For instance, I want to convert my x and y points into a new coordinate system. The value at each location will stay the same, but the actual x and y will change by a factor of 2e-8*x^(4.3192). The problem is, this isn't in true log/log space.

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

I tried changing the axes of the graph into log/log space, but they don't line up. What can I do?

Comment: And you can't handle this at the data level? Basically modify the `x` and `y` arrays by that factor you are referring to?

Comment: I do, but then it doesn't graph it properly, my graph currently plots the data as a large array, not as a set of x and y values with a given intensity. Hence my question.